# How to respond to http and keep the goroutine running ? Go

Tags: go

I'm wondering if it's possible to respond to a http request using the std [http](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package and still keep the go routine alive ( e.g. run a task intensive task ). The use case is that I need to receive a http request and then call back that service after few minutes

Comment: Which goroutine are you referring to ? And try to make your question more clear.

Comment: Yes, you can do this however consider that the client will eventually timeout.

Comment: You'd probably want to spawn a new goroutine for it. Even better, dump the task into a worker pool in order to ensure the number of concurrent tasks doesn't get out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

Just spawn a new goroutine from your handler and keep that alive as long as you like.